# Case equation without curly brace

Tags: equations, braces, cases

I want to have a `case equation` without the left `curly brace`. I am using

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
    \frac{I}{Z}=12+\frac{7}{Z}[eV] & ,Z<13 \\
    \frac{I}{Z}=9.76+58.8Z^{-1.19}[eV] & ,Z\geq13  \\
    \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which is perfect for my case, except for the big, left curly brace!

Comment: I wasn't aware of that...So I will do so for the answers that really worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You may better use `aligned`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  \frac{I}{Z} &= 12+\frac{7}{Z}\;[eV],     && Z<13 \\
  \frac{I}{Z} &= 9.76+58.8Z^{-1.19}\;[eV], && Z\geq13
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Then use a regular `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
  \begin{array}{ll}
    \frac{I}{Z}=12+\frac{7}{Z}[eV], & Z<13 \\
    \frac{I}{Z}=9.76+58.8Z^{-1.19}[eV], & Z\geq13
  \end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The alignment specification of `{ll}` inserts the contents `l`eft-aligned in both columns, while a redefinition of `\arraystretch` adds some vertical padding to each row. See [Column padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31704/5764).

Since each element inside an `array` is set in `\textstyle`, fractions are smaller than usual by default. Adding `\displaystyle` will increase the fraction presentation, similar to [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\dfrac`.

Comment: @Werner -- i really think the `\\` at the end of the last line of the `array` is a bad idea.  i know it was in the original question, so i should probably comment it there, but this comment will get to you more reliably, as well as to the op.