# How to draw two arrows, one in the numerator and another one in the denominator in equations?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
H(\&)=  \dfrac{R_1 + R_2(\&C_2R_1 +1)}{\&C_2R_1 +1}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I would like to achieve the following output:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a simple `array` environment, based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142671/80509):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 H(\&)=  \dfrac{R_1 + R_2(\&C_2R_1 +1)}{\&C_2R_1 +1}\begin{array}{l}
\rightarrow \text{Ceros}\\
\rightarrow \text{Polos}
\end{array}

\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Related: [Case equation without curly brace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72903/case-equation-without-curly-brace?noredirect=1&lq=1).